# Debug keystore for Android expired - INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_INCONSISTENT_CERTIFICATES- IntelliJ

Tags: android, intellij-idea, keystore

I am working with IntelliJ IDEA 12.0.4.

I have repeatedly received the INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_INCONSISTENT_CERTIFICATES message when installing my app to my emulator and my phone.

I believe the error came at the time my debug.keystore expired, and I solved the problem on the emulator by uninstalling the old version.

However I do not want to uninstall the app on the phone as this will delete user data.

I have also tried signing the app with my release key and then install that on the phone (by copying the APK file and executing it) - but that install was also rejected for certificate reasons. Shouldn't that be OK?

What should I do?

PS: For the avoidance of doubt - I have only one development PC, and only one certificate...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android has no way of knowing that your debug key is related to your release key.

If your app has access to the SD card, you can use a command prompt to copy your data files to the SD card using something like this.

```
adb -d shell
run-as <packagename> sh
cp <files> /sdcard/
```

Your phone does not have to be rooted to do this, but run-as only works on the debug version of your app.

Answer (score 0):

The phone doesn't know whether something is a release or debug key.  It just knows it's signed with a key.  So no, you can't update a debug signed copy with a release signed copy unless you use the same key for release and debug.

There's no real way around an uninstall here.  If your phone is rooted, you can pull the files off and restore them after the new install.

Answer (score 0):

The old installed .apk has different certificate than the new going to be installed.

So the solution is:

`uninstall the existing .apk`
`and then re-install the new .apk`